# Forms without labels

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have some Rails forms and they all have labels (custom or default). But i want to take the label away and just put a placeholder on the `text_field`. However this doesnt work. He just gives me the default label as well.

```
 <%= f.text_field :nome_pt, :validate => true, :id => "nome_pt",  label: false %>
```

I don't want custom labels... I want no label at al

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

```
hide_label: true
```

This works like a charm